# Xamarin Error: No Android Platforms installed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-2015

is anybody familiar with the errors showing in attached screenshot. can anyone help to resolve?There are two errors when i tried to build sample xamarin android app.

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1nI2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK manager and install API levels on your machine. Search for SDK manager in your programs. And download the Android SDK platform-tools, which is located in Tools folder

For more information take look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Visual Studio/Xamarin is not finding your Android SDK installation.

Xamarin.Android Manual Installation

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/